# Turtle's Position Doesn't Change After Moving with Arrow Keys

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics, keyboard-events

I'm trying to find the position of a turtle which is being controlled by the user using the wasd keys. What I've noticed is that the turtle's position never appears to change in the print statements inside the `while (True)` block.  Do you guys have any advice (relevant code below for reference)?

Note: I know `while(True)` is bad form; this is just a spike.

```
import turtle

def Setupcontrols(turtle, window):
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.sety(turtle.ycor()+15), 'w')
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.setx(turtle.xcor()-15), 'a')
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.setx(turtle.xcor()+15), 'd')
  window.onkey(lambda: turtle.sety(turtle.ycor()-15), 's')
  window.listen()

def Setupuser(myTurtle,window):
  window.bgcolor("white")
  window.setup (width=400, height=400, startx=0, starty=0)
  myTurtle.speed(2)
  myTurtle.shape('turtle')
  myTurtle.color("blue")
  myTurtle.penup()
  myTurtle.delay(0)
  myTurtle.left(90)
  window.exitonclick()

def main():
  wn=turtle.Screen()
  Gameturtle=turtle.Turtle()
  Setupuser(Gameturtle, wn)
  Setupcontrols(Gameturtle, wn)
  while (True):
    print(Gameturtle.position())

main()
```

Comment: `while True:` isn't just bad form here: for the (infinite) duration of that loop, the `print` inside of it is *absolutely the only thing your program is doing*.

Comment: I mentioned that this is a spike (aka Proof of Concept). I have other working code, but this feature is causing me some headaches. Any advice related to the position not changing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only use functions for your onkey commands. Example:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()

def moveForward():
   t.forward(1)

screen.onkey(moveForward,'right')
screen.listen()
```

Hope this helps!